# How to modify mount options in an OpenBSD install?

Tags: mount, system-installation, openbsd

How exactly can I modify different mount options for a FS at an OpenBSD install? IT's crazy, but I just can't find it. I'm at here:

```
W # Use (W)hole disk or (E)dit the MBR?
E # Use (A)uto layout, (E)dit auto layout, or create (C)ustom layout?
```

but I just can't find it in the "?" pages of disklabel..

Comment: The [openbsd faq's on installation](http://openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Morefdisk) should help.

Comment: hmm... I read it but It didn't provide info how to set mount options.. the only way is after install - before reboot - go to shell mount the / and edit /etc/fstab?

Comment: The fdisk stage specifies what part of the disk is to be used - these are partitions as you know from windows or mac. The next step (bsdlabel) slices the disk space from the partition you want to use into filesystems which have different mount points (confusingly these are called partitions on openbsd - freebsd calls these slices). Section 4.6.4 in the above link shows disklabel usage which is where the mountpoints are configured. Following the link to the man bsdinstall page shows n allows you to name the mount point for an existing partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the install is done, and before rebooting, edit `/mnt/etc/fstab` (the installed system's root is mounted under `/mnt` during install).